# Call functions in the form f(T&& t) repeatedly without using std::move(t) again?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "A.h"

void second(const A& a)
{
    std::cout << "void second(const A& a)." << std::endl;
}

void second(A&& a)
{
    std::cout << "void second(A&& a)." << std::endl;
}

void first(const A& a)
{
    std::cout << "void first(const A& a)." << std::endl;
    second(a);
}

void first(A&& a)
{
    std::cout << "void first(A&& a)." << std::endl;
    second(a); //Make this call void second(A&& a) without using std::move(a) again?
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "int main()." << std::endl;

    A a;
    first(std::move(a));

    std::cin.sync();
    std::cin.get();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do here?

Answer (score 2):

```
second(a);
```

It cannot call `second(A&&)` because `a` is an lvalue (as it has a *name*).

To call `second(A&&)` you need an rvalue. So you need to convert `a` into an rvalue, for which you have to use `move` or do manual explicit conversion:

```
second(std::move(a));        //invokes second(A&&)
second(static_cast<A&&>(a)); //invokes second(A&&)
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the function

```
void first(A&& a)
```

the parameter `a` is a named value, and thus an lvalue.

You really wouldn't want it to be moved away at the first function call anyway, as that would cause a lot of trouble if you want to use `a` several times in your function. Consider

```
void first(A&& a)
{
    second(a);
    third(a);
    fourth(a);
}
```

You wouldn't want the call to `second` move the value away from `a`.

Comment: Or to be more explicit functiins taking `&&` references are allowed to "trash" their input in a sense.  They do not pass this request onto functions they call because you might want to call more than one.

Answer (score 1):

Do you find the process of writing rvalue reference overloads for every function tedious, and are looking for a way to save yourself from that tedium?  Consider condensing your overloads into a single function which takes its parameters by value, then moves them where they need to go.

So, in other words, these two functions...

```
void foo(X const& x) {
    bar(x);
}
void foo(X&& x) {
    bar(std::move(x));
}
```

...become this one function

```
void foo(X x) {
    bar(std::move(x));
}
```

The savings (in typing and maintainability) become exponentially greater for each extra parameter.  It sometimes costs an extra move, but never an extra copy (unless of course, there is no move constructor).